# Firefox and Google Chrome differences creating or sorting an array using .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, firefox

I'm trying to make a minesweeper, and something weird has happened, in Chrome or Chromium-based navigators everything seems and works just fine, but in firefox, all of the bombs generated clumped together at the end, or the start of the array, is there any difference in how sort() works with parameters?

I'll leave the piece of the code that generates the board.

```
  

    function createBoard() {
        //create an array with shuffled bombs
        const bombsArray = Array(bombAmount).fill("bomb");
        const emptyArray = Array(width * width - bombAmount).fill("valid");
        const gameArray = emptyArray.concat(bombsArray);
        const shuffledArray = gameArray.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
        for (let i = 0; i < width * width; i++) {
          const square = document.createElement("div");
          square.setAttribute("id", i);
          square.classList.add(shuffledArray[i])
          grid.appendChild(square);
          squares.push(square);
```

Comment: FYI https://javascript.info/array-methods#shuffle-an-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

> Note: `compareFunction(a, b)` must always return the same value when given a specific pair of elements a and b as its two arguments.

In your case, you don't do this, which gives undefined behaviour, most likely dependent on the sorting algorithm that is used by the browser's `Array.sort` implementation.

You can ensure that the random value for a particular array item remains stable by mapping to a new array with a random `order` property, sorting, then mapping back again:

```
const shuffledArray = gameArray
  .map((value) => ({ value, order: Math.random() }))
  .sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order)
  .map(({ value }) => value)
```

This probably isn't the most efficient way of shuffling an array, but a minesweeper board is so small that it won't matter.

Comment: Didn't know different browsers use different Array.sort() implementation, thought it was inherent to the programing language. You've been really helpful!

Comment: @MaxSerket Chrome has a swiss-army knife of 3 sorting algos (last time I checked) for different sort scenarios. IIRC, Mozilla uses mergesort.